# Regex between two characters - Matched between many same characters

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string

`[ 14.21 |     | Pobiedziska Letnisko             2 11.16   | 1       ]`

I need a value between second "|" character and number "2" or "1"
[image]
Only this part of string without the "|" character and without the number.
I was trying this pattern

```
(?<=\|).+?(?=(1|2))
```

But as you can see, this pattern is not good as the match started with the first character "|" and I need to do it from the second "|" character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a capture group starting after the second pipe char matching till the first occurrence of 1 or 2.

Note that `.+?` can also match `|` so it will cross the `|` if the 1 or 2 is after a pipe char at the right.

```
^[^|]*\|[^|]*\|(.+?)\b[21]\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fegT5w/1)

If you don't want to cross newlines or pipe chars, you can extend the negated character class like `^[^|\r\n]*`

Another option using lookarounds as in your question with a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) not crossing a pipe char:

```
(?<=^[^|]*\|[^|]*\|)[^|]+(?=\b[21]\b)
```

- `(?<=^[^|]*\|[^|]*\|)` Assert 2 pipe chars to the left of the current position
- `[^|]+` Match any character except `|`
- `(?=\b[21]\b)` Postive lookahead, assert 2 or 1 to the right

[.NET Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5e%5b%5e%7c%5d*%5c%7c%5b%5e%7c%5d*%5c%7c%29%5b%5e%7c%5d%2b%28%3f%3d%5cb%5b21%5d%5cb%29&i=%5b+14.21+%7c+++++%7c+Pobiedziska+Letnisko+++++++++++++2+11.16+++%7c+1+++++++%5d)

Comment: Yeah, the second regex is what i need. Thank you!